# Where is the Monoid instance on Comparison defined?

Tags: haskell, monoids

`newtype Comparison a` is defined in [`Data.Functor.Contravariant`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/Data.Functor.Contravariant.html#Comparison).

In the version of this module defined in [`contravariant-1.5`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/contravariant-1.5/docs/src/Data.Functor.Contravariant.html#Comparison), the `Monoid` instance on `Contravariant` is defined as follows:

```haskell
instance Monoid (Comparison a) where
  mempty = Comparison (\_ _ -> EQ)
  mappend (Comparison p) (Comparison q) = Comparison $ mappend p q
```

`Data.Functor.Contravariant` is also defined in base (as of GHC 8.6.1, apparently). 
In base, the `Monoid` instance on `Comparison` is defined [as follows](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/Data.Functor.Contravariant.html#Comparison):

```haskell
deriving instance Semigroup (Comparison a)
deriving instance Monoid (Comparison a)
```

What enables the instance for `Monoid (Comparison a)` to be automatically derived in base?

And where should I look to see the definitions of `mempty` and `mappend` for it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For `newtype`s, with `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving` enabled, the instance is obtained using the instance of the underlying type.

So, `mempty @ a -> a -> Ordering` is used (ditto for `mappend`), and then rewrapped as `mappend :: Comparison a`.

Note that this ultimately involves the semigroup/monoid instances for function types `b -> c` and the ones for `Ordering`.

Answer (score 5):

The `Comparison` type is just a `newtype` over `a -> a -> Ordering`.

`Ordering` is a `Semigroup` instance defined in, I think, `GHC.Base`.

Another relevant instance of `Semigroup` is:

```
Semigroup b => Semigroup (a -> b)
```

That is, any function type `a -> b` has a `Semigroup` instance if `b` has a `Semigroup` instance.

You can think of `a -> a -> Ordering` as `a -> (a -> Ordering)`, i.e. a function that takes `a` as input, and returns `(a -> Ordering)` as output. Since `(a -> Ordering)` is a `Semigroup` instance, then `a -> (a -> Ordering)` is, too.

The same line of reasoning applies to `Monoid`.

Finally, as chi wrote in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54020051/126014), `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving` takes care of the rest.