# Haskell - Sort by first second element and then by first element

Tags: sorting, haskell

I have a list of tuples and I would like to sort it by second element (descending) and then by first element (ascending).

My code looks like this:

```
sortedOcc :: Eq a => [a] -> [(a, Int)]
sortedOcc = sortBy (flip compare `on` snd) . occurences
```

and this is the first sorting by the second element of list returned by `occurences` (function). How should I add the second sort (ascending) by the first element?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Data.Ord` module provides a `Down` newtype whose purpose is solely to reverse the ordering.

It also provides a [`comparing` function](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.1.0/docs/Data-Ord.html#v:comparing):

```
comparing :: Ord a => (b -> a) -> b -> b -> Ordering
```

which must be fed some *transformation function* before it can be passed to `sortBy`.

Like this:

```
$ ghci
 GHCi, version 8.8.4: https://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
 λ> 
 λ> sortBy  (comparing (\(a,v) -> (Down v, a)))   [(1,2),(1,3),(5,2),(5,3)]
 [(1,3),(5,3),(1,2),(5,2)]
 λ>
```

The values returned by the transformation function are then sorted using their own “natural” order. In our case, this is the [lexicographic order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographic_order) on pairs of ordered types.

Overall, the code would require an `Ord a` constraint:

```
sortedOcc :: Ord a => [a] -> [(a, Int)]
sortedOcc = sortBy (comparing (\(a,v) -> (Down v, a)))  .  occurences
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd probably write this using [the `Monoid` instance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54020051/1486968) on `Ordering` and on function types.

Sorting on the second value in the tuple looks like `` flip compare `on` snd ``, as you've already determined, while sorting on the first value looks like `` compare `on` fst ``.
These can be combined Monoidally with `<>`.

```hs
d :: [(String , Int)]
d = [("b", 1), ("a", 1), ("c",3), ("d",4)] 

sortedD = sortBy ((flip compare `on` snd) <> (compare `on` fst)) d
```

Answer (score 2):

I know that the rest of the answers are shorter, but I recommend you to implement these lazy functions yourself before using the already Haskell implemented ones, so you understand how it works.

```
-- Order a list of tuples by the first item
orderBy1stTupleItem :: Ord a => (a, b1) -> (a, b2) -> Ordering
orderBy1stTupleItem tup1 tup2
  | item1 > item2 = GT
  | item1 < item2 = LT
  | otherwise = EQ
  where
      item1 = fst tup1
      item2 = fst tup2

-- Order a list of tuples by the second item
orderBy2ndTupleItem :: Ord a1 => (a2, a1) -> (a3, a1) -> Ordering
orderBy2ndTupleItem tup1 tup2
  | item1 > item2 = GT
  | item1 < item2 = LT
  | otherwise = EQ
  where
      item1 = snd tup1
      item2 = snd tup2

-- Wrapper Function: Order a list of tuples by the first item and later by the second item
orderTuplesBy1stThenBy2ndItem :: (Ord a1, Ord a2) => [(a2, a1)] -> [(a2, a1)]
orderTuplesBy1stThenBy2ndItem listTuples = 
    sortBy orderBy2ndTupleItem (sortBy orderBy1stTupleItem listTuples)
```

**Example**

```
let exampleListTuples = [(1,2),(0,8),(6,1),(3,6),(9,1),(7,8),(0,9)]
```

Then let's get the 1st list, ordered by the first item of each tuple:

```
> listOrderedByTuple1stItem = sortBy orderBy1stTupleItem exampleListTuples
> listOrderedByTuple1stItem
[(0,8),(0,9),(1,2),(3,6),(6,1),(7,8),(9,1)]
```

Now we order this result list by the second item of each tuple

```
> sortBy orderBy2ndTupleItem listOrderedByTuple1stItem
[(6,1),(9,1),(1,2),(3,6),(0,8),(7,8),(0,9)]
```

Or, you can just run the wrapper function `orderTuplesBy1stThenBy2ndItem` as follows:

```
> sortBy orderTuplesBy1stThenBy2ndItem exampleListTuples
```

Answer (score 1):

What is  [`sortBy`](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=sortBy)'s signature?

```
sortBy :: (a -> a -> Ordering) -> [a] -> [a]
```

This means that its first argument must have the type `a -> a -> Ordering`:

```
sortedOcc :: Eq a => [a] -> [(a, Int)]
sortedOcc = sortBy g . occurences

g :: a -> a -> Ordering
g = (flip compare `on` snd)
```

but that means that

```
g :: a -> a -> Ordering
g x y = (flip compare `on` snd) x y
      = flip compare (snd x) (snd y)
      = compare (snd y) (snd x)
```

and so to add your requirement into the mix we simply have to write it down,

```
      = let test1 = compare (snd y) (snd x)
            test2 = compare (snd y) (snd x)
        in ......
```

right?

*The above intentionally contains errors,* which should be straightforward for you to fix.

<sub>A word of advice, only use point-free code if it is easy and natural for you to read and write, and *modify*.</sub>